# Evaluating Postfix Expression using stack and array of char with C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, stack, postfix-notation

I don't know where I do it wrong. Every time I 'pop' in the end of main function it always gave me nothing. I have checked by popping every time before and after I pushing after an operation, and the result is there. But everytime I pop outside the for-loop, the stack gave me nothing. Thanks before, I'm very appreciate your answer.
P.S = I'm not allowed to use class or OOP. So please don't gave me an answer using those method.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    int top;
    int data[20];
}stack;

void initStack(stack &S)
{
     int i;
     S.top=-1;
}

int pop (stack &S)
{
    int number;
    number = S.data[S.top];
    S.top = S.top - 1;
    return number;
}

void push(stack &S, int number)
{
    S.top = S.top + 1;
    S.data[S.top] = number;
}

void compute(stack &S, char *ch, int n)
{
    int result;
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= n-1; i++)
    {
        if (ch[i] == '*')
        {
            int operand1 = pop (S);
            int operand2 = pop (S);
            result = operand1 * operand2;
            push(S, result);
        }

        else if (ch[i] == '/')
        {
            int operand1 = pop (S);
            int operand2 = pop (S);
            result = operand1 / operand2;
            push(S, result);
        }

        else if (ch[i] == '+')
        {
            int operand1 = pop (S);
            int operand2 = pop (S);
            result = operand1 + operand2;
            push(S, result);
        }

        else if (ch[i] == '-')
        {
            int operand1 = pop (S);
            int operand2 = pop (S);
            result = operand1 - operand2;
            push(S, result);
        }

        else
        {
            result = ch[i] - '0';
            push(S, result);
        }
    }
}

main()
{
    stack ST;
    char ch[20];
    initStack(ST);
    cout<<"Please enter the operation: ";
    gets(ch);
    int n = strlen(ch);
    compute(ST, ch, n);
    pop(ST);
}
```

Comment: You never actually "pop" in the `main` function, nor print anything, so how do you know there's a problem?

Comment: I accidentaly forgot to pop in the script I wrote in stackoverflow, but if I add pop into it, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Then please edit the code in the question to the one you actually have a problem with.

Comment: okay, I have edit the code. Thanks before for your response :)

Answer (score 1):

Well if I'm understanding right the problem is a very simple one. You need to *print* the value you are popping

Replace

```
pop(ST);
```

with

```
cout << pop(ST) << '\n';
```

Obviously you won't see anything unless you remember to print what you want to see.

Comment: I guess I'm too focusing on the algorithm and then I forgot to add cout, now it works. Thanks a lot :)